# Do simple drawing primitives in Matlab exist?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

In most graphics APIs you can easily draw **graphics primitives** with functions like `drawLine`, `drawCircle`, `drawText`, `fillRect`, and so on.

**Is there anything similiar and simple in Matlab?** I know various means of plotting, but I've never seen and never found some really simple drawing API.

(Even though my code is in Matlab, I'm really tempted to implement my graph-like visualisation in Java because I really do not see a good way to just draw graphics primitives in Matlab...)

Comment: How about the `shapeInserter` API - http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.shapeinserter-class.html There are also built in functions such as `viscircles` and `rectangle` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB has nice plotting and visualizing tools. <sup>[Citation needed]</sup>

The very flexible [`annotation`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) function has many options, which are well documented. There are are also the simpler [`line`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) and [`rectangle`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) commands. To set the scale of the drawing area, you can create an invisible [`axis`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html).

```
figure;
axis([0,1,0,1],'off'); % drawing area: x=[0,1], y=[0,1]
line([0.9,0.8],[0.8,0.2],'Color','b')
annotation('rectangle',[0.4,0.4,0.2,0.2],'Color','red' )
annotation( 'ellipse', [0.2 0.7 0.2 0.1], ...
            'Color', 'r', ...
            'FaceColor', [0.5,1,1], ...
            'LineStyle', '--', ...
            'LineWidth',2)
```

Comment: Never heard about that even though I've been using Matlab for years now and tried hard to find those primitives...